# Wrong/weird render when using haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following code:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.navbar-responsive-collapse
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav
  - if true
    %li a
  - else
    %li b
```

This renders to:

```
<div class='navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'></ul>
<li>a</li>
</div>
```

Why doesn't it render the li inside the ul? If I put the code without the if:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.navbar-responsive-collapse
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav
    %li a
```

I get the expected

```
<div class='navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
<li>a</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Am I doing something stupid?

I'm using hamlit 2.4.0 with rails 5.0.0rc2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you do this:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.navbar-responsive-collapse
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav
    - if true
      %li a
    - else
      %li b
```

Comment: This works, the last time I used haml, I used it with the `haml-rails` gem, with version 0.4, and this extra indentation was not needed ...

Comment: yeah I guess that happens a lot.